# Obtain html source code to Excel multiple rows

Tags: vba, excel

I am very new to Excel VBA and I need to scraping a website's HTML.
This is a difficult task to me now and I have a workaround - Using VBA to obtain the whole HTML source code to a worksheet, and then scraping with Excel functions.

Here is the VBA code from other sites which obtain the whole HTML source code to a worksheet:

```
Sub ExtractWeb()

'to refer to the running copy of Internet Explorer
Dim ie As InternetExplorer

'to refer to the HTML document returned
Dim html As HTMLDocument

'open Internet Explorer in memory, and go to website
Set ie = New InternetExplorer
ie.Visible = False
ie.navigate "http://www.google.com"

'Wait until IE is done loading page
Do While ie.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
DoEvents
Loop

'show text of HTML document returned
Set html = ie.document

Worksheets("test").Select
Range("A1").Value = html.DocumentElement.outerHTML

End Sub
```

The problem is: The whole source code, which contains many lines, is pasted into a single cell.
However I expect that each line of the source code is inserted into a single row.
How should I correct my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim arr

arr = Split(html.DocumentElement.outerHTML, vbLf) 'or vbCR or vbCrLf

Worksheets("test").Range("A1").Resize( UBound(arr)+1, 1 ).Value = arr
```

Comment: Thanks. However the code pastes the first line of HTML source code to all cells. How I can fix it? I try to use loop to paste the lines one by one, the result set is correct but the performance is horribly low....

Comment: I find the reason. The reason is the array is horizontal but the target range is vertical. I fix it with the code: Worksheets("test").Range("A1").Resize(UBound(arr) + 1, 1).Value = Application.Transpose(arr) . Thanks.

Comment: @Shiman -  That's what I get for not testing my answer.  Glad to see you figured it out.