# How to get a particular link from a web page's source code?

Tags: html, vba, excel

i need a macro in VBA that is able to extract all HTML source code from an url contained in a EXCEL cell and put it line by line in all different Excel cells.
I've previously searched different solutions on the net but not finding the right one.

Thanks for helping ;)

**EDIT:**
thanks to the libraries just insert i could also test another macro that i've previously found on the net:

```
Sub Naviga()
Dim texto As String
Dim objIE As Object
Dim DestUrl As String

DestUrl = "http://www.google.it"

    Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    objIE.Visible = False
    objIE.Navigate2 DestUrl

Do
DoEvents
Loop Until objIE.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

Range("A" & 1).Value = objIE.document.body.innerHTML

End Sub
```

and it's works, but unfortunately i would like that the link was acquired directly from a cell in excel, and when the line is copied, the next line, start with the next cell, the cell below.
How can i modify the macro?

**EDIT 2:**
The solution is near, i've just fixed the code, now is more clean:

```
Sub EstrSorgPag()
Dim IE As Object

    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    IE.Visible = False
    IE.navigate Range("H1")

Do
DoEvents
Loop Until IE.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

Range("A" & 1).Value = IE.document.body.innerHTML

End Sub
```

but lacks the last part where the macro should copy the content cell by cell (A1,A2,A3,A4... and so on)

**EDIT 3:**
Hello guys, i wrote this short code that extract all links from a web page's source code:

```
Sub EstraiURLdaWeb()

Dim doc As HTMLDocument
Dim output As Object


Set IE = New InternetExplorer
IE.Visible = False
IE.navigate Range("L1")

Do
    DoEvents
    Loop Until IE.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

Set doc = IE.document
Set output = doc.getElementsByTagName("a")

i = 5
For Each link In output
    Range("A" & i).Value = link
    i = i + 1

Next

MsgBox "Fatto!"

End Sub
```

But i would need to extract this in particular:

```
<li class="bubble"><span><a href="/soccer/finland/veikkausliiga/standings/YTtR3YWr/">Main</a></span></li>
```

how can I do?

Comment: The purpose of this site is for programmers to help one another develop; it is not a free-coding site.  Even if it was a free-coding site, what does "put it line by line in all different Excel cells" mean?  Break your requirement into little steps.  First you need to read the source of the URL. Look at the related questions (down on the right) where you will find several questions on this topic.  One you have imported the source as a string, you can think about how to break it into little bits.

Comment: Won't the manual copy of a source code be enough? Right click the page, select *"View Page Source" or something similar* and copy to excel. You should get what you need... If you need VBA solution and you can't program in VBA, well, now is the best time to learn. :)

Comment: oh sorry, but i can't  program in VBA :(
"put it line by line in all different Excel cells" mean that this macro sript should put every source code lines into every single excel cell, because one cell may contain limited number of text character...

Comment: no because i should repeat this action over and over again, for extracting  some data that i need from different websites

Comment: i've found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25791378/obtain-html-source-code-to-excel-multiple-rows that is the same request of mine, but that code don't work for me :'(

Comment: Why doesn't that other code work for you?  Apart from having a hard-coded URL, it seems like it addresses your issue.

Comment: because there is a "compile error" on that line: ie As InternetExplorer "User-defined type not defined"

Comment: You need to set *References* to some libraries. In VBE, go to Tools menu > References > *Find and check both* **Microsoft HTML Object library** and also **Microsoft Internet Controls**

Comment: wow thanks! now the program run but no result came out and at the end there is another error: "Subscript out of range"

Comment: Hi friends!, i've edited the post with a VBA code, can you now help me?

Comment: Hi friends!, i've just edited the post for the 3rd time, can you now help me?

Comment: Hi. We do not receive any notifications when you edit or comment your own post. You can notify one of us with @[nickname]. I will look at your edits in next 2 days.

Comment: @BranislavKollár ok thanks a lot! :)

Comment: Isn't the `<a>` you want in the `output` collection? Or you want just that ONE?

Comment: @BranislavKollár i want only that code line, instead my code give me all links contained in a web page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Verify the `<a>`'s InnerHTML or InnerText

If you already got all the `<a>` tag elements, you can loop through them all (you got this already) and create a logical condition, if each particular element contains the keyword you are looking for.

```
Set output = doc.getElementsByTagName("a")

For Each link In output
    If link.InnerHTML = "Main" Then
        Range("A" & i).Value2 = link
    End If
Next
```

### Combine more `GetElement(s)` methods

To get more narrow collection of HTML elements, you can combine multiple `GetElement(s)` methods. Like so:

You can get all the HTML elemens with specific class:
`Set BubbleCollection = doc.getElementsByClassName("bubble")`

Then you can scan this collection for `<a>` tags:
`Set output = BubbleCollection.getElementsByTagName("a")`

Check how many elements you've got (optional for debugging/refining the search):
`Debug.Print output.length`

Comment: Hi, sometimes it happens an "Automation error" on a window and i click on "debug" and the VBA show me the error (Set ie = New InternetExplorer), but how is that possible? I even other macros with the same code and they work

Comment: @ALIENATO Hi. Please consider creating a new question on SO with some details, maybe link to this post, so we can help you.